# Phrase or idiom for "Either I or they"

Tags: phrases, idiom-requests

Consider the following statement:

> Russia also maintains a faulty foreign policy i.e. either Russia or the West, and there is nothing in between. I.e. no option for cooperation.

How can I use a phrase/idiom/proverb to represent this?

Comment: For once the right phrase is, let us say, grammatically eccentric.  “...a faulty ‘us and them’ foreign policy towards the West...”

Comment: Or a faulty “us versus them”

Comment: What does the question title have to do with the body of the question?

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't clear, but if you are asking for an idiom that describes the (deliberate) error in Russia's foreign policy, then it is usually referred to as [a false dichotomy or a false dilemma](http://www.philosophy-index.com/logic/fallacies/false-dilemma.php):

> A false dichotomy or false dilemma occurs when an argument presents two options and ignores, either purposefully or out of ignorance, other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

**winner takes all**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Winner)

> a competition in which the victor is granted all possible prizes

As in:

Russia's entire foreign policy with the West: **winner takes all!**

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***all or nothing***

> Russia maintains an ***all-or-nothing*** foreign policy- They allow no option for cooperation.

Cambridge says of [***all or nothing***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/all-or-nothing):

> relates to doing something either completely or not at all.
> *She either loves you or hates you- It’s either all or nothing with her.*
>
> *The government has rejected the all-or-nothing approach in favor of a compromise solution.*